# using mappings inside structs

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I'm trying to use a mapping inside a struct:

```
struct PoolStruct {
    uint currentUserID;
    uint activeUserID;
    uint price;
    uint minimalReferrals;
    mapping(uint => address) poolUserList;
  }
```

the code compiles, so i guess it's somehow permitted.
The problem starts when i try to assign to that property:

```
PoolStruct memory pool;

pool = PoolStruct({
  currentUserID: 1,
  activeUserID: 1,
  price: POOL_PRICES[i],
  minimalReferrals: POOL_MINIMAL_REFERRALS[i]
});

pool.poolUserList[1] = msg.sender;
```

get an error on the last line...

```
TypeError: Member "poolUserList" is not available in struct Definitions.PoolStruct memory outside of storage.
       pool.poolUserList[currUserID] = msg.sender;
       ^---------------^
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: What error are you getting? What is `currUserID`?

Comment: @goodvibration, i edited the question with the error. currUserID is a uint (1)

Comment: Yeah, well, you can use `mapping` only in storage (i.e., non-local) variables. So the same goes for a `struct` which holds a `mapping`.

Comment: You probably wanna take that mapping outside the `PoolStruct` structure, and redefine it as `mapping(uint => PoolStruct) poolUserList`.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: that makes sense, i'll give it a try

Comment: i'm also gonna have a look into storage

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that mappings can only live in storage. When you define `PoolStruct memory pool;`, the mapping member cannot be created in memory, and therefore the memory struct should be treated as if the mapping member never existed (for solidity < 0.7.0).

Starting from solidity 0.7.0, the line `PoolStruct memory pool` will produce an error saying that structs containing (nested) mappings must have storage as data location.

Comment: @hrkshnn, Then, how should I declare? 'PoolStruct storage pool' also seems to throw an error. Saying 'Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed.'

Comment: @Sang-hoon-Shin what does the error say?

Comment: It says "Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed"

Comment: Please check my question: 
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87451/solidity-error-struct-containing-a-nested-mapping-cannot-be-constructed

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the mapping outside the struct. you do not have to keep inside the struct

```
     mapping(uint => address) poolUserList;
```

Answer (score 0):

A mapping can only be returned in a struct in a function, if the function is internal or when using a library.