# Solidity Error: Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct, solc

My version of solc:

```
"solc": "^0.7.1",
```

When I try to construct a struct that contains mapping, I got this error:
"Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed"

This is my solidity code.

Campaign.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

contract Campaign {
    struct Request {
        string description;

        // I declared a mapping inside of a struct.
        mapping(address => bool) approvals;

    }
    constructor(uint256 minimum, address creator) {
        ...
    }

    function createRequest(string memory description) public onlyManager {
        Request memory newRequest = Request({ 

            // Here the compiler gives me an error

            description : description

        });
    }
    ...
```

It says

```
Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed.
```

Please help me.

Comment: You cannot create a mapping (or a struct containing one) in memory.

Comment: @goodvibration I've also tried a storage and just 'Request newRequest'. But it throws the same error

Comment: Since nothing in your code suggests that you even need this struct, the easiest solution would be to simply get rid of it.

Comment: Storage is for existing items, not for new ones!

Comment: Aha, then how can I create my request with a given variable (in this case, description)?

Comment: Like I said - first of all, there is nothing in your code which suggests that you even need this structure to begin with. So either explain why exactly you want it, or just get rid of it altogether. Second, even assuming you explain why you need it, you still need to explain why you need the mapping inside it. Because if you don't, then you can (and should) simply declare the mapping outside the structure and not inside it. Please fix your question to make some sense!

Comment: It is because I need to check whether each of the requests has voted or not. I want to build a voting function in my smart contract. So I made a mapping(address => bool) to check if the address from one specific request is true or not.

Comment: @goodvibration This was actually working before the `solidity version 7.0` ,  when `push` was used

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is in the construction, i.e., `Request({ description: description })` Therefore changing the location of `newRequest` from `memory` to `storage` will not help.

If you really want to make it work, create a state variable, say, `mapping (uint => Request) requests`. Now, inside your function, you can write `Request storage newRequest = requests[index]` where `index` will get incremented later.

For a reference, see: [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.1/070-breaking-changes.html#mappings-outside-storage)

Comment: Thank you very much! Then is there any way to put a specific address (which is from Request struct) to the key(instead of uint) of a mapping?

Comment: You can change it to `mapping(address => Request)`

Comment: Thank you for yout help. I'll try.

Comment: Where do you set the mapping for `approvals`? @hrkrshnn

Comment: @alper you don't really set the mapping for approvals. If you have defined a local struct inside a function, then it has to be a pointer to a storage struct.

Answer (score 16):

from 0.7.0 do like below:

```
 struct Request{
            string description;
            uint value;
            address recipient;
            bool complete;
            uint approvalsCount;
            mapping(address => bool) approvals;
        }
        
    uint numRequests;
    mapping (uint => Request) requests;
    
    function createRequest (string memory description, uint value,
            address recipient) public{
                Request storage r = requests[numRequests++];
                r.description = description;
                r.value = value;
                r.recipient = recipient;
                r.complete = false;
                r.approvalsCount = 0;
            
        }
```

Comment: With this, I got error: 
Type Error: Data location can only be specified for array, struct or mapping types, but "storage" was given.

Comment: What about the approvals mapping in the Request struct? How can you update that?

Answer (score 5):

This should be enough:

```
function createRequest(string memory description) public onlyManager {
    Request storage newRequest = requests.push();
    newRequest.description = description;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a mapping (or a struct containing a mapping) in memory.

So, convert your code from this:

```
contract Campaign {
    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping(address => bool) approvals;
    }

    Request[] public requests;

    function createRequest(string memory description, uint value, address recipient) public restricted {
      Request memory newRequest = Request({
          description: description,
          value: value,
          recipient: recipient,
          complete: false,
          approvalCount: 0
      });
      requests.push(newRequest);
    }
}
```

to this

```
contract Campaign {
    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping(address => bool) approvals;
    }
    
    uint numRequests;
    mapping (uint => Request) requests;
    
    function createRequest(string memory description, uint value, address recipient) public restricted {            
        Request storage r = requests[numRequests++];
        r.description = description;
        r.value = value;
        r.recipient = recipient;
        r.complete = false;
        r.approvalCount = 0;
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.0/types.html?highlight=struct#structs)

Answer (score 2):

I wish to add some background info, to help those transitioning from a managed-memory environment (like the .NET CLR) to the EVM:

- Usually, you may have instantiated reference types which allocate memory (on the heap). Since solidity EVM memory is more restricted, solidity instead initializes mappings in contract ***storage*** instead (instead of in ***memory***). Since instantiating a `struct` on the stack utilizes `memory`, this is why this error message pops up when trying to instantiate a solidity `struct` that contains a `mapping`.
- Usually, you may have asked a runtime for new memory (e.g.: using the `new` keyword in C#). In solidity, this step is abstracted away from the developer & instead the solidity EVM automatically does it for us behind the scenes. Specifically, this occurs when the `mapping` variable is declared. This is why the code examples on this page don't show a step for memory allocation, & instead just jump straight to setting `mapping` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `struct` with a mapping inside. Create a local `mapping` in your contract at the top level.

Comment: Thank you! How can I connect the mapping with a specific Request? Because I want to check if the request has voted or not (as True or False)

Comment: Use a common identifier. You keep a mapping with ids and a mapping with ids to structs